# Owin/Katana, Basic Authentication and WindowsIdentity

Tags: owin, owin-middleware

We are building a ASP.NET Web API 2 service self-hosted in OWIN/Katana. Because of some security requirements the app uses Basic Authentication, which results in System.Web.Http.ApiController.RequestContext.Principal.Identity being of type HttpListenerBasicIdentity. But what we need is WindowsIdentity/WindowsPrincipal. What is the best way to go about it? Middleware? Something else?